# how to transform 'JSON-like' string into real JSON data

Tags: python, json, string

I now have a string called str1 like this:

```
{u'price': 542.23, u'name': u'ACME', u'shares': 100}
```

and I want to transform it into a real JSON data.

the way that uses

```
data = json.loads(str1)
```

doesn't work. Do you have any good ideas? (with Python)

Comment: How come did you get a `u` prefix in your string? Did you do something like: `str1 = repr(some_object)` ?

Comment: this is because of  `Unicode` - `u`

Comment: @SuperSaiyan the string is like "{u'price': 542.23, u'name': u'ACME', u'shares': 100}" . The whole line is a string. In fact, this string is in a file. And I want to get a JSON data from the file. that's it.

Comment: Try running `eval` on that string. It's not json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import ast

s = "{u'price': 542.23, u'name': u'ACME', u'shares': 100}"
d = ast.literal_eval(s)

> type(d)
<type 'dict'>

> d['price']
542.23
```

By the way, eval is not safe.

ast.literal_eval raises an exception if the input isn't a valid Python datatype, so the code won't be executed if it's not.

Use ast.literal_eval whenever you need eval. If you have Python expressions as an input that you want to evaluate, you shouldn't (have them).

Comment: thanks a lot! I search many json topics about this, none of them mentions ast.literal_eval .